# Инициализация функций

Tags: c++, функции

Почему иногда функции присваивается какое-то значение, например:

```
class Test
{
public:
Test() = default;
Test(Test &test) = delete;
virtual void Free(void* ptr) = 0;
};
```

Что конкретно происходит после присваивания?
И стоит ли так делать?

Comment: В заголовке написано "инициализация". В тексте написано "присваивание". Но инициализация и присваивание - уже совершенно разные вещи. И это при том, что здесь нет ни инициализации, ни присваивания.

Comment: А что это такое тогда?

Comment: http://archive.kalnytskyi.com/2012/01/23/introduction-to-cpp11-new-specifiers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спецификатор `default` указывется вместо тела функции и означает реализацию по умолчанию и может применяться только к специальным функциям-членам:
конструктор по-умолчанию;
конструктор копий;
конструктор перемещения;
оператор присваивания;
оператор перемещения;
деструктор.

Спецификатор `delete` помечают те методы, работать с которыми нельзя.

```
`virtual void Free(void* ptr) = 0;`
```

это присваивание означает, что виртуальная функция чистая(определяется только в производных классах